# a4j:support not rerendering the radio buttons instantly

Tags: jsp, web, ajax4jsf

I have two radio sets and one is dependent on the other. I want to disable the second one when there is a specified change in first one. I have used `a4j:support` tag to accomplish it as shown in the code below

```
<td align="left">
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{wcbBean.wcbVO.IS_UNABLE_TO_PERFORM}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Yes" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="No" />
<a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{wcbBean.setDegImpairState}" reRender="rbDegImpair">
</a4j:support>
</h:selectOneRadio>         
</td>
<td align="right">Degree of Impairment:</td>
<td align="left">
<h:selectOneRadio id="rbDegImpair" value="#{wcbBean.wcbVO.DEGREE_OF_IMPAIRMENT}" disabled="#{wcbBean.wcbVO.DISABLE_DEGREE_IMPAIR}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="TOTAL" itemLabel="TOTAL" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="PARTIAL" itemLabel="PARTIAL" />
</h:selectOneRadio>         
</td>
```

The second set is not rendering again on changing the first set but after a single click anywhere on the page. Why I need to click on the page to disable the second set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the above problem was IE need another click to fire the `onchange` event while the code runs fine in firefox. To make it work in IE, I simply change the `onchange` event to `onclick` event and now I dont need any extra click.